# Button with background image and corner radious in android

Tags: android

I am trying to make a button with a backl ground image. Again I want to apply some state style with selector xml.
I have used this xml below as style and the other one as selector. But the background image is not showing up. Also I want to apply some corner radious to the button

Please help.

```
<style name="HomeMenuButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#FF000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">-1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">5</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_back</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/red" />
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
            <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="2dp" 
                android:right="5dp" android:bottom="2dp" /> 
            <corners android:radius="15dp" /> 

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >         
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/red" />
            <solid android:color="@color/blue"/>
            <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="2dp" 
                android:right="5dp" android:bottom="2dp" /> 
            <corners android:radius="15dp" /> 

        </shape>    
    </item> 
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried your code and it shows the background as you intended.

Have you added a android:style attribute into you layout xml? Something like this:

```
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello world!"
    style="@style/HomeMenuButton"
/>
```

Moreover your original state drawable doesn't show pressed state. You may need to change it a little bit by moving the pressed state item to before the normal state.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >         
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/red" />
            <solid android:color="@color/blue"/>
            <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="2dp" 
                android:right="5dp" android:bottom="2dp" /> 
            <corners android:radius="15dp" /> 
        </shape>    
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/red" />
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
            <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="2dp" 
                android:right="5dp" android:bottom="2dp" /> 
            <corners android:radius="15dp" /> 
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is the button shown with radius ? I want a corner radius to the button also.

Comment: Yes the button is shown with radius as in the picture (the bottom button)

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/825/ss01x.png/

Comment: Have you tried putting a image as background. The sample u have shown does not seem to have an image. Could you please retry again